# AngularJS view without using main ui-view template?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I'm creating an application that provides a logged in user with the ability to create a poll (with questions and choices) in their dashboard.

Once the poll has been created I would like to redirect to the poll page, which will have a unique url (ex: http://example.com/p/3eRr4g6).

I would like this page to NOT use the dashboard template.

How does one accomplish this?

**Here's my dashboard view:**
[image]

**Example Poll Page/Template:**
[image]

UPDATE: To show my current index file and how I have it structured. (In reply to koox00's response)

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-purple sidebar-mini">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>

            <div ng-include="'components/sidebar/sidebar.html'"></div>

            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div ui-view></div>
            </div>

            <div ng-include="'components/footer/footer.html'"></div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Will the created page have dynamic structure or static ?

Comment: Dynamic if you count the poll data, which will be populated when users vote.

Comment: Do you think you can use `$window.location.href = 'http://example.com/p/3eRr4g6';`
and use custom template to that page?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm currently using $location to redirect to the page. I'm going to have to test your theory. The only problem I can see I will have is that I'm going to lose my $scope data (auth, etc).

Comment: do you use `ui-router`?

Comment: yes, I'm currently using ui-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [named](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) views.

Create a state that loads the default template in that view e.g `main` and make every other state a child of this one if you want to share data.

In the desired state you can load over the main view the html you want.

#### update

default.html

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>

    <div ng-include="'components/sidebar/sidebar.html'"></div>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-include="'components/footer/footer.html'"></div>

</div>
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="main"></div>
</body>
```

take a look at [nested states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views) also if you want to share data between states parent/child.

Comment: That would require me to put my header/sidebar/footer (ng-includes) into all of my partials though, correct? As of right now I have them in the index.html outside of the ui-view. I've updated my original post to reflect what I'm talking about

Comment: Yeah, but you can leave only `ui-view` in the index.html and create another partial which will be loaded in ui-view from the parent state.

Comment: I tried this and I think it would work, the only problem I have with it is that it reloads my dynamic sidebar and header every time a user clicks from one page to another which seems redundant.

Comment: ok I dont know how you reload the sidebar but every service is in the parent's state resolve gets called only once so you can avoid lets say auth etc.. happening twice

Comment: I know your answer is correct, I'm just not grasping the concept of how to correctly implement it.

Comment: Can you post some example routes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103495/discussion-between-koox00-and-jayson-h).